# Short story where Earth was created as an elementary school science project

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

When I was 10, in the mid-to-late-1980s, I had a collection of short stories that was edited by Asimov. The one I'm interested in was the story of the creation of Earth told as though it was a school science project for an elementary school child.

On reflection they might have made our solar system too, but they were mostly interested with Earth. The story ended with the Teacher telling the student to throw it out, but the student planning to secretly keep it.

Can anyone remember the name of the book, or the name of the story itself? I'd love to find it again.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'as though it was a school project' ?  Also, to assist with timing, in what year were you 10 ?

Comment: The story was told from the viewpoint of the child, (s)he was describing something they were making in class. On reflection they might have made our solar system too, but they were mostly interested with Earth. The story ended with the Teacher telling the student to throw it out, but the student planning to secretly keep it. Timing wise, it would have been mid to late 80s.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

["Kindergarten"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?51975) by [James E. Gunn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_E._Gunn_(writer)), also the (unaccepted) answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135344/poem-or-short-story-alien-child-creates-earth-for-a-science-project); first published in [*Galaxy Magazine*, April 1970](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58442+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v30n01_1970-04#page/n117/mode/2up). You can read it online [here](http://www.rswheeldon.com/wierd/kindergarten.html). The Asimov anthology you read it in may have been [*100 Great Science Fiction Short Short Stories*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?43) or [*Creations: The Quest for Origins in Story and Science*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?8195) or [*Young Extraterrestrials*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?276716) among others.

Comment: I think that the book I read it in was Young Extraterrestrials.