# "Incubators?" maybe the title or the last word

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This story was in an anthology in the 60's or 70's. It concluded that our universe is actually an experiment or incubator...
Any thoughts which it was?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This question could use some more details; do you recall any of the other stories in the anthology, or its cover?  Check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for story identification questions to see if they help you recall any additional details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are a lot of stories that use this premise, c.f. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38648/short-story-where-earth-was-created-as-an-elementary-school-science-project or https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/profiles/1MmQjXrkwp98jNdc17j3tr3/mice. We need more details to flesh this out.

Comment: FWIW, http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=incubator&type=Fiction+Titles

Answer (score 4):

Isaac Asimov's "[Breeds There A Man...?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breeds_There_a_Man...%3F)"

Final lines:

> Blaustein looked at the stars.
>
> Incubators?

It was first published in *Astounding*, June 1951; you can read it online at [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v47n04_1951-06_Gorgon776#page/n73/mode/2up).

Comment: If this is it, then it is a duplicate of [this earlier question.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94386/short-story-force-field-inventor-commits-suicide)